# Liferay - Cannot access Look and Feel

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

Using Liferay 6.1 CE GA 2 I have added portlet to page. Recently I have faced the following issue:

When I click on Options > Look and Feel I receive "You do not have the roles required to access this portlet."

But I am using admin account, how can that be? Let me know if there are any ideas.

Comment: MORE DETAILS on the issue:

- For some reason portlets on the pages which I have created a month ago work fine and Look and Feel loads with no issues.
- But if I add the same portlet on new page - Look and Feel is not working.
- If I add default Web Content Display to the new page - Look and Feel does not work
- If I add Web Content Display to the page I have created  a month ago - Look and Feel works fine there

I have double checked pages permissions - they are equal.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old issue but I thought this answer might help others as it was a pain to figure out.  I had this exact same issue and found it was caused by changing the value of the `portlet.add.default.resource.check.whitelist` property in portal-ext.properties.  Somehow modifying this list made it so that I couldn't access the Look and Feel menu of any portlet, I always got the "You do not have the roles required to access this portlet" error.  Upon commenting out the `portlet.add.default.resource.check.whitelist` property I was able to once again access the Look and Feel menu.  I have a embedded portlets in my theme that need to be on this whitelist so I was worried that the Look and Feel menu would be broken if I added the property back, but apparently Liferay was just caching invalid permissions and removing the property cleared them because I was able to add the property back and restart the server and everything worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. We have not faced this issue for a while since we have reconfigured portal multiple times and not sure what exactly fixed the issue, but your comment does make sense and may be helpful in future.

Answer (score 1):

I faced it once and hence had put below things in `portal-ext.properties` and it started working. Also, remove the portlet once and reconfigure it.

```
theme.css.fast.load=true
theme.images.fast.load=true
javascript.fast.load=true
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Is there any way to fix that without removing portlet? I have changed specified settings and restarted server. For some reason style of pages has broken and I still cannot access Look and Feel.

Comment: May be you should trace your look and feel using Browser web developers and check which `CSS` is affecting it.

Comment: can you please be more specific regarding your suggestion? What should I check there?

Comment: Please check which is the CSS attribute causing the problem and from where it is being referred. Is it being referred from your Theme or your Portlet..

Comment: Sorry, but your suggestion makes no sense: 1) as I mentioned in comment for question I have the same issue while using OOTB Web Content Display portlet. 2) theme is the same for all site pages. 3) all site pages have the same settings. So I am not sure what and how should be checked. "Please check which is the CSS attribute causing the problem" - how can I debug this problem when server has no error messages in output? Please share exact ideas if you have them. Thank you